# Local flash slideshow that reads images within a directory

Tags: gratis, flash, slideshow

Is there any free software flash slideshow I can download and configure setting a directory path so it loads images from there and present them in a slideshow?

Comment: Use HTLM5 and flash is not needed.  Flash is a security nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

Why worry about using Flash - and limiting the browsers that can access it in the process when you can do it all with JavaScript - much more portable that way.

Just one example that a quick google produced was [jquery-slider](http://www.justinwhall.com/directory-jquery-slider/).

Comment: This require that all the images in the directory have a fixed name: config.directory + config.filebase + slideNumber + '.' + config.extension.
So, to use it, I have to rename all the images.

Comment: Just use imagemagick `convert source_dir\*.* --resize=800x800 targetdir\basename%02d.jpg`

Comment: I looking for a solution for final users.

Comment: @JuanjoConti: please add more information to your question. Who are the final users? Why Flash? Why does the built-in Windows slide show not suffice?

Comment: Don't the site policies require that you use the software yourself? "A quick google" would not meet that policy